# String data to array using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Using Posh-SSH module to read a csv file directly from a sftp server,

$Content = Get-SFTPContent -SFTPSession $Session -Path "/test.csv" -ContentType String

-ContentType MultiLine errors out with "Get-SFTPContent : Failed to get content to file /test.csv"

Once read $Content is a one large single page with type System.String.

Is there a way to store the data to an array / hashtable to be used in the next steps of the script? do not want to export to a file, want to do the conversation in the memory (will need to delete the file straight after Get-SFTPContent is complete)

csv file in the folder is simple,
get-aduser -properties * | select Name,Enabled,mobile,SamAccountName ... | Export-Csv c:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation

Appreciate some assistance ...

Comment: `ConvertFrom-Csv` is what you're looking for I believe

Comment: $Proper = ConvertFrom-Csv $Content

Surely can’t be this easy ..  :)

didn’t even had to put any custom headings – because the file was proper csv in the previous life